# Rails show different object every day

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I want to match my user to a different user in his/her community every day. Currently, I use code like this:

```
@matched_user = User.near(@user).order("RANDOM()").first
```

But I want to have a different @matched_user on a daily basis. I haven't been able to find anything in Stack or in the APIs that has given me insight on how to do it. I feel it should be simpler than having to resort to a rake task with cron. (I'm on postgres.)

Comment: You mean like that the @matched_user will be the same for all the requests in the same 24 hours ?

Comment: I hadn't thought of it that way, but yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I find myself hankering for shared 'memory' or transient state, I think to myself "this is what (distributed) caches were invented for".

```
@matched_user = Rails.cache.fetch(@user.cache_key + '/daily_match', expires_in: 1.day) {
  User.near(@user).order("RANDOM()").first
}
```

**NOTE**: While specifying a TTL for cache entry tells Rails/the cache system to try and keep that value for the given timeframe, there's *NO* guarantee that it *will*. In particular, a cache that aggressively tries to reclaim memory may expire an entry well before its desired `expires_in` time.

For this particular use case, it shouldn't be a big deal but in cases where the business/domain logic *demands* periodically generated values that are *durable* then you really have to factor that into your database.

Comment: Ah! always finding ways that Rails already contains what people need. I was going to suggest a table of neighbors with a user_id foreign key (unique). Then they could compare the `updated_at` field with `Time.now.midnight.since(86400)`. So if the created_at is more than 24 hours old it could then be told to update with a random person. But caches are much better.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know about this type of caching in Rails until now. Great answer, much more efficient than mine.

Comment: Whoa, this is definitely Rails beyond my knowledge. It's currently turning up 'nil' though, when I plug in this exact code into the controller, whereas the previous code for @matched_user used to work. Do you have any idea why the cache might be failing? Is this an issue with dev mode?

Comment: @MatthewMelone You may have previously tried to `fetch` the same key and the block returned `nil`. When that happens, until the cache expires that key then subsequent calls to `fetch` for the same key will, of course, return `nil`. In particular, try `Rails.cache.delete(key)` or `Rails.cache.clear` to reset the cache.

Answer (score 1):

How about using PostgreSQL's `SETSEED` function? I used the date to seed so that every day the seed will change, but within a day, the seed will be consistent.:

```
User.connection.execute "SELECT SETSEED(#{Date.today.strftime("%y%d%m").to_i/1000000.0})"
@matched_user = User.near(@user).order("RANDOM()").first
```

You may want to seed a random value after using this so that any future calls to random aren't biased:

```
random = User.connection.execute("SELECT RANDOM()").to_a.first["random"]
# Same code as above:
User.connection.execute "SELECT SETSEED(#{Date.today.strftime("%y%d%m").to_i/1000000.0})"
@matched_user = User.near(@user).order("RANDOM()").first
# Use random value before seed to make new seed:
User.connection.execute "SELECT SETSEED(#{random})"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have split these steps in different sections just for readability. you can optimise query later.

1) Find all user records till today morning. so that the count will freeze.

```
usrs_till_today_morning = User.where("created_at <?", DateTime.now.in_time_zone(Time.zone).beginning_of_day)
```

2) Pluck all ID's

```
user_ids = usr_till_today_morning.pluck(:id)
```

3) Today date it will be a range (1..30) but will remain constant throughout the day.

```
day_today = Time.now.day
```

4) Select the same ID for the day

```
todays_user_id = user_ids[day_today % user_ids.count]

@matched_user =  User.find(todays_user_id)
```

So it will give you random user records by maintaining same record throughout the day!!